# Unknown column 'gameApp_questions.id' in 'field django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

hi everybody i make a quizz app in django i make choose 6 questions from database  in views.py

```
 question_list = Questions.objects.filter(grade=15,subject=2).order_by('?')[:6]        
    for i, question in enumerate(question_list):
        question.point = i + 1
        question.save()
    context['questions'] = question_list
    
    return context
```

and i have a eror mesage OperationalError at /gameApp/gameplay
(1054, "Unknown column 'gameApp_questions.id' in 'field list'")

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: i run migrations it make  no changes detect

Comment: What about `makemigrations`?

Comment: i try to change database before and this mistake is apper but i found a copy of project before i try to change database and this is solve my problem thank you for your time